# Can a specific noun be concrete or abstract?

Tags: abstract-nouns, concrete-nouns

Fact: something that has actual existence

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fact

1. Can “fact” be a concrete noun or an abstract noun?

fact=god (concrete) fact=space exploration (abstract)

2. Can “fact” be partly concrete and partly abstract?

fact=a person had a sweet dream.

person (concrete) dream (abstract)

Answer (score 1):

A noun can have several meanings or senses.  And it is the meaning of the noun that is concrete or abstract.

The word "fact" is principally applied to statements.  When we say "God is a fact", what we mean is "The statement "God exists" is a fact."

If I had an apple you would not say "I have a fact".  An apple is a fruit, not a fact. The statement "I have an apple" is a fact.

The categories of Concrete and Abstract are not types of *English* words. They describe the meanings of those words, and so apply to any language. As "facts" are statements that are true, they are not material objects and so in this sense "fact" is abstract... just like this meaning is in other languages.

But learning about abstract and concrete nouns is not part of your study of English language, it is part of your study of language in general.

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, a specific noun might be considered either concrete or abstract. For example, energy is a physical property, so some might consider it concrete, but it has no material substance, so some might consider it abstract.

However, as @JamesK notes, a "fact" is a concept, not a physical thing, so it is abstract. God (another word that could go either way depending on context) might be considered concrete, but the fact that God exists is certainly abstract.